# Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlins-coroutines-android:1.3.9

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building a project using Android Studio and while run it I get this as build output:
Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlins-coroutines-android:1.3.9

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.backgroundthread2'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.backgroundthread2"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlins-coroutines-android:1.3.9"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I'm building a project using Android Studio and while run it I get this as build output:
Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlins-coroutines-android:1.3.9